# "I love me" vs. "I love myself"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In [Two and a Half Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Two_and_a_Half_Men_characters) pilot, Jake and Charlie had a conversation after Alan decided to move to their mother's.

> Jake: "How come you don't have any kids?"

> Charlie: "I don't know. Maybe because **I love me**
> more than anything in the world."

Grammatically, Charlie should have said "I love myself", right? Is it a common mistake in daily conversation?

Comment: No, *me* is correct. It's the object of the sentence. It's not a mistake at all. (*Myself* is also correct.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Do they mean the same thing in this context?

Comment: Yes, they both mean the same thing in this context.

Comment: Really? I have only ever heard *me* used like this in a joshing context. There may be nothing wrong with it grammatically but we usually use the reflexive pronouns: I love myself, you love yourself he/she/it loves him/her/it-self, we love ourselves, they love themselves. It's the same as any other verb: I cut myself. Don't blame yourself etc. Have you heard you love you? We love us?? They love them???

Comment: I agree with @OldBrixtonian: the normal choice is _myself_. I think there has been a rise in _I love me_ with the growth of personal development programmes, but I would still call it a marked form: marked for humour or special emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have pointed out, it's usually worded "I love myself" instead of "I love me".  In fact, almost always. You ought to use the reflexive in such a case.

However, this is not a mistake.  Quite the contrary.  It's a *humorous* situation, somewhat in the same spirit as referring to oneself "in the third-person".

> "because Charlie loves himself, that's why".

Anyway, if Charlie had said "myself" it would have been too correct, too serious, and therefore not right for the line*.

( * A "line" in a television show or movie is what's being spoken by an actor. Definition: "A sentence of dialogue, especially in a play, movie or the like.")

> Is it a common mistake in daily conversation?

No, these words are rarely mixed up by mistake.

Comment: Thank you. Does "not right for the line" mean "not right in this context"? I googled ["for the line"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&ei=5qciX-KXBPK_0PEPw_ySqAs&q=define+%22for+the+line%22&oq=define+%22for+the+line%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwA1DeGljeGmDLHWgAcAB4AIAB9QGIAboEkgEFMS4wLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjiornz6PTqAhXyHzQIHUO-BLUQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) but didn't get any explanation of it.

Comment: @JQQ , updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. In conclusion, "I love me" is more humorous than "I love myself" in this particular company, right?

Comment: @JQQ, right, it's funnier (in this particular dialogue).